# rails 3: using devise for authentication, how to ALSO allow access to a report page with a guid instead of login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My rails 3 app only needs a single user login per account (e.g., no roles). I'm using Devise and am very happy with it.

But my users needs to be able to share a few of the screens (status reports mostly) with other managers who do not need or want login accounts...

I was thinking of creating and storing a guid for each such 'external' report (unique for each account+report) so a link such as

```
http://myapp.mydomain.com/pagename?token=GUID_GOES_HERE
```

would access that page (but ONLY that page)

Questions:

a) is there a way to allow the logged-in account user to access a page but ALSO allow a guid to bypass the devise authentication

b) is there a better way for account Users (say, a regional manager) to share certain report screens with non-logged-in users (say, store managers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those pages do not require login then they aren't they truly public pages?  Sounds to me like you should create a new controller that does not require login but requires the token.  the route could be something like,

`get 'public_reports/:token' => 'public_reports#view'`

And the controller action would find that report based off the token and render the appropriate view..

```
class PublicReport < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:view]

  def view
    @report = Report.find_by_token(params[:token])
    if @report
      #render view...
    else
      #render report_missing view
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Great response, thank you. what confuses me though is when the actual logged in user is logged in an access the reports, would they still be able to navigate freely between their login-screens and the token-screens and maintain their login?

Comment: I figure just as freely as navigation between any homepage and other pages.  If you want to have code on the PublicReport views that requires login use devise's user_signed_in? method (or whatever your user model is called) to prevent breakage from people that are not signed in.