# Rails and DocRaptor, override authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 4 and DocRaptor in order to convert an html page to pdf. 
The problem is I'm also using devise 3 for authentication.

Devise's log in page is the root if you're not authenticated. Therefore, when DocRaptor pulls the html from a show page, it actually pulls the log in page.

Is there a way to ignore authentication for a call by DocRaptor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with a `skip_before_filter` and even pass us a secret token of some sort to prevent/obscure public access. The below answers have a couple good examples. As a DocRaptor employee, happy to help!

[rails 3: using devise for authentication, how to ALSO allow access to a report page with a guid instead of login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146361/rails-3-using-devise-for-authentication-how-to-also-allow-access-to-a-report-p)

[What is the best way to bypass devise authorization for a specific record marked public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573353/what-is-the-best-way-to-bypass-devise-authorization-for-a-specific-record-marked)

Comment: Thanks for the idea! It works great, but I'm having trouble implementing the secret token idea. Any ideas for that?

Comment: It could be as simple as adding "?token=nobody_will_ever_guess_this" to every url and then checking to make sure `params[:token] == "nobody_will_ever_get_this"` in an `:if` on the `skip_before_filter`. The second link I posted has an example of this behavior.